# limiting behaviour of converging loops on a torus

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Suppose (L<sub>n</sub>) is a sequence of loops in a torus  S<sup>1</sup> × S<sup>1</sup> converging in the Hausdorff metric to some set L in the torus. Suppose also that for each loop L<sub>n</sub> the projection map p:S<sup>1</sup> × S<sup>1</sup> -> S<sup>1</sup> defined by p(x,y) =x when restricted to L<sub>n</sub> is not null-homotopic, then can we conclude that the restriction of the projection map p to L is also not null homotopic? Or are there counter examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: the map p : L → *S*<sup>1</sup> is not nullhomotopic.

If p : L → *S*<sup>1</sup> was nullhomotopic, then it would factor through the universal cover ℝ of *S*<sup>1</sup>.
The inclusion ι : L → *S*<sup>1</sup> × *S*<sup>1</sup> would therefore factor through ℝ × *S*<sup>1</sup>.
Let ι' : L → ℝ × *S*<sup>1</sup> denote a lift of ι,
and let L<sub>(0)</sub> := ι'(L).
The subset L<sub>(0)</sub> ⊂ ℝ × *S*<sup>1</sup> is then one of the connected components of the preimage of L in ℝ × *S*<sup>1</sup>.
Let us call the other components L<sub>(*n*)</sub> for *n* ∈ ℤ.

Let *C*<sub>0</sub> ⊂ ℝ × *S*<sup>1</sup> be a loop in that
separates L<sub>(0)</sub> from L<sub>(1)</sub>.
We may also assume that *C*<sub>0</sub> is not nullhomotopic in ℝ × *S*<sup>1</sup> [this still needs a small argument...].

The projection *C* ⊂ *S*<sup>1</sup> × *S*<sup>1</sup> of *C*<sub>0</sub> is then a loop in the complement of L,
 and
represents the element (0,1) of ℤ×ℤ = π<sub>1</sub>(*S*<sup>1</sup> × *S*<sup>1</sup>).

Since L lies in the complement of *C* and L<sub>*n*</sub> → L in the Hausdorff metric,
 there exists an *n* such that L<sub>*n*</sub> lies in the complement of *C*.
This contradicts your assumtion that p : L<sub>*n*</sub> → *S*<sup>1</sup> is nullhomotopic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears that the notation L<sub>n</sub> is being used in two different contexts. could you please clarify. 

Comment: I fixed the mismatch of notations.

Answer (score 3):

EDITED. The following example should not be conisdered as a contre-example, 
it is just a well known example of a pathology that can  happen.

EXAMPLE. $L$ is composed of a union of the vertical circle $(0, S^1)$ and a disjoint $R^1$ that is emdedded in $T^2$ in such a way, that it accumulates to $(0, S^1)$ from both sides. This $R^1$ projects one-to one to the horisontal circle without a point and can be represented a as graph (function of $x$), than if is given by the following formula:

$y= (sin(1/x))$

The point is that such $L$ can be Hausodrff approximated by a sequence of circles $s_n$ that are not null-homotopic ($s_n$ wiggles more an more near the vertical circle $(0, S^1)$ as $n\to \infty$).

The problem with this example, is that the topology on the union of $S^1$ and $R^1$ that we should take (I guess) is the toplogy induced from $T^2$. And for this induced topology, I guess the projection to the horisontal cicle is non null-homotopic...

Comment: This is not a counterexample.

Comment: I dont understand why the inclusion composed with the proyection is nullhomotopic. 